# How to count the spaces in the text area in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def changed(event=None):
    if text_editor.edit_modified():
        text_changed = True.
        words = len(text_editor.get(1.0, 'end-1c').split())
        characters = len(text_editor.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
        count = 0
        for space in str(characters):
            if space.isspace() == True:
                count += 1   
        status_bar.config(text = f"Characters: {characters} words: {words} spaces: {count}")
    text_editor.edit_modified(False)
```

I go the result: NO error message: Just the space: 0

Comment: This shows no signs of attempting to debug the problem yourself. Have you examined what `str(characters)` is immediately before the loop? Just a simple print statement is all you need to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
characters = len(text_editor.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
```

is most likely not what you want. It sets `characters` to the length of the text, i.e., to a **number**.
Then you do

```
for space in str(characters):
```

This iterates over all the characters in the string representation of the number. That will never contain any space.

To get this right you have to set `characters` to the actual text, not its length.

Comment: I am new to python, I didn't get it. The code above is from the recent project that I'm following in the youtube tutorial.

Comment: Actually, the above code is my attempt to modify the existing code where the program counts characters and words. But I didn't find the counting of space. So, it was my effort which really didn't work well! Please help.

Comment: You'll have to specify what exactly you did not get (I just spotted a typo in my answer: `next` vs. `text` in the last sentence, maybe that is what confused you?)

Comment: I modified my code: characters = len(text_editor.get(1.0, 'end-1c')) to characters = len(text_editor.get(1.0, 'end-1c').replace(' ', '')) to skip the space counting.
My program calculates the number of characters, the number of words I typed in the text-editor. And all of these are displayed in the status bar. But I made an attempt to count the spaces too. I used isspace() method to count the spaces using for loop. However, the space counts 0 and there is no error message. So, Is there the other way coding to calculate the spaces? This is what I expect and went wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you do `characters = len(text_editor.get(...))`. Like I said, this sets `characters` to the *length* of the string. Assume that the string has 12 characters. Then `characters` holds the * number* 12 and `for space in str(characters)` will iterate over the string "12". You first have to get the actual value from the editor: `text = text_editor.get(...)`. Then you can count the characters in that text: `characters = len(text)`. And finally, you can iterate over the characters in the text and count the spaces: `for space in text`.